# How can I use callback function from ajax in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I use callback function from ajax in another function

I've got function with ajax:

```
function correct_date(raw_date){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                showTheValue(result);
            }  
     });
}

    var showTheValue = function(correct_day_value) {
     console.log(new Date(correct_day_value.DATE_NEW).toLocaleDateString('de-DE'));
     return correct_day_value;
    };
```

And I want to have the response/data value from ajax in another function like that:

```
function correct_start_date() {
        document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = showTheValue();
    }
```

How can I use response data from ajax in another function ?

Comment: You have to place `var showTheValue = function ...` before the ajax, or make it an named function `function showTheValue() {}`.

Comment: I've tried like this: 
`function showTheValue(correct_day_value) {document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = showTheValue();}`

And i've got this error in console:
`index.html:87 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

Comment: How are you currently calling `correct_date` and `correct_start_date` functions?

Comment: where did you call correct_date?

Comment: @eisbehr you are wrong! that function is created at the initial time when the file is loaded. It starts reading from beginning and creates all the functions & variables first. Then, when the ajax is performed you can use those created functions and variables.

Comment: @eisbehr No that's not how JS works.

Comment: @webmaster Consider [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hk6w9yma/1/). There may be a difference because `success` is late binded and executed `async`. Not tested.

Comment: @BadHorsie See my comment before. That is exactly how JS workes. There is a difference between `named functions` and variables containing functions.

Comment: @eisbehr, success is not late bound, it is "executed" async. The methods are set to memory at "load" time, not "run"  time. I think you are confused about the scopes. In your example, It cannot work because all the statements work at the "load" time. So if all the processes are at the same scope, you have to order them. But here, the Ajax is called at runtime which is asynic, so all the methods are already created at  the loadtime so it will work.

Comment: And yes, absolutely "there is a difference between named functions and variables containing functions" as seen in your example. But here, they are not run at the "initial phase" but in your sample, they are run at the initial phase. This is the difference here.

Comment: And that's why I'm said *I'm not sure about this* in this case.

Comment: If the method was like "function correct_date(raw_date){}()" then yes, it will cause error because it is called when created (at load/initial time). But , to run that function you have to call it externally at "runtime" where all functions and variables are initiated.

Comment: If you are not sure just try to understand by reading the comments and answers. Nobody is a wisdom, everybody is always a student till death ;) We may be wrong too but above all the things we talked, I think you are wrong for this question's phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me:

```
function correct_date(raw_date){
        return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                    method: 'correct_date',
                    date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json'
     });
}
```

And then I can insert it wherever I want like this:

```
function parse_correct_day() {
      .
      .
      .
      .  
        var parse_correctday_value = correct_date("12.1.2016");
        parse_correctday_value.success(function (data) {
            var corrected_date = new Date(data.DATE_NEW);
            document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = corrected_date.toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use those two functions like:

```
function correct_date(raw_date){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                correct_start_date(showTheValue(result));//***
            }  
     });
}

var showTheValue = function(correct_day_value) {
     console.log(new Date(correct_day_value.DATE_NEW).toLocaleDateString('de-DE'));
     return correct_day_value;
};

function correct_start_date(correct_day_value) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = correct_day_value;
}
```

Or if the "correct_start_date" is used according to a case:

```
function correct_date(raw_date){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                var correct_day_value = showTheValue(result);
                if (/* some case */) {
                    correct_start_date(correct_day_value);//***
                }
            }  
     });
}
```

Or wait until the value is set by the Ajax:

```
var globalVar = null;
function correct_date(raw_date){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                globalVar = showTheValue(result);
                //correct_start_date(globalVar);
            }  
     });
}

var showTheValue = function(correct_day_value) {
     console.log(new Date(correct_day_value.DATE_NEW).toLocaleDateString('de-DE'));
     return correct_day_value;
};

function getGlobalVar() {
    if(globalVar == null) {
        window.setTimeout(getGlobalVar, 50); 
    } else {
        return globalVar;
    }
}

function correct_start_date() {
    if (
    document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = getGlobalVar();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this, because it's async. But declaring the variables `showTheValue` and `setValue` after `$.ajax`, they could be `undefined`. You have to make it a named function then, or place it before the AJAX call ...

Comment: No no I just mis-typed the second function, now fixed. Which are run asynchronously? I think the answer from Ajax is asynchronous. Then from there, you can use any function at "success" phase.

Comment: I tried this by calling

localDate(); in other function and it gives me: LocalDate is undefined

Comment: Why did you use localDate() ? Does Javascript has a function like that? this error is normal.

Comment: No, your first code:
var setValue = function(correct_day_value) {
   var localDate = new Date(correct_day_value.DATE_NEW).toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
   console.log(localDate);
   return localDate;
};

And then I use localDate() to get the value to another function, but it's undefined

Comment: You cannot use localDate variable as "localDate()" because it is not a function. Also it is inside the scope of the function, not outside of it so it is undefined when trying to reach outside of the scope of the function. If you want to use the value at another scope, you must create a public variable and assign the value to it. Then you can check the value and use. Check my third version, updated it it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function correct_date(raw_date, callback){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                return callback(result);
            }  
     });
}

function showTheValue() {
    correct_date(raw_date, function(correct_day_value) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = correct_day_value;            
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can you the JavaScript Promise.

> http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

```
function get(url) {
  // Return a new promise.
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do the usual XHR stuff
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', url);

    req.onload = function() {
      // This is called even on 404 etc
      // so check the status
      if (req.status == 200) {
        // Resolve the promise with the response text
        resolve(req.response);
      }
      else {
        // Otherwise reject with the status text
        // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
        reject(Error(req.statusText));
      }
    };

    // Handle network errors
    req.onerror = function() {
      reject(Error("Network Error"));
    };

    // Make the request
    req.send();
  });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of calling 2 functions you should return the result from the function `showTheValue` and then show the response in the desired elements :

```
function correct_date(raw_date){ 
    return $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "../date/correct.php",
            data: {
                method: 'correct_date',
                date: raw_date
            },
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                console.log(result.DATE_NEW);
                //You need to check the return value of your function and add the value accordingly
                document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[1].value = showTheValue(result);
            }  
     });
}

function showTheValue(correct_day_value) {
   var localDate = new Date(correct_day_value.DATE_NEW).toLocaleDateString('de-DE');
   console.log(localDate);
   return localDate;
};
```

Comment: Could you try adding a comment before downvoting to be polite and give feedback what you felt was wrong with the answer

Comment: I didn't downvote you, I just saw your answer and gonna try it :)

Comment: Maybe because your code will never work?! You declared a anonymous function which will not get used anytime. Instead of complain about downvotes you should test your code before just posting it. ;)

Comment: @eisbehr, that was a typo my bad, you could have hinted on that earlier, will update

Comment: Could you consider upvoting if this helps @eisbehr

Comment: @BadHorsie thanks, but it feels bad when trying to help someone and due to a small mistake/typo lose some of that hard earned reputation.